# How to build netty by source code? I failed in test code because of assertequals ambiguous method call

Tags: macos, netty

I want to build netty from source code. I pull 4.1 from GitHub. When i want to run maven, I have some problem in test code.

I can run `maven install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` to build project. But when I want to run netty-example code, I see some error in test code.

I can not remove all test code, so I can not run code in this project.

This is for a jdk1.8, macos ,idea2019.

```
@Test
    public void testFlushViaDisconnect() {
        final AtomicInteger flushCount = new AtomicInteger();
        EmbeddedChannel channel = newChannel(flushCount, false);
        // Simulate read loop;
        channel.pipeline().fireChannelRead(1L);
        assertEquals(0, flushCount.get());
        assertNull(channel.readOutbound());
        channel.disconnect();
        assertEquals(1, flushCount.get());
        assertEquals(1L, channel.readOutbound()); // error this line.
        assertNull(channel.readOutbound());
        assertFalse(channel.finish());
    }

Error:(150, 9) java: ambiguous method call of assertEquals
  org.junit.Assert method  assertEquals(long,long) and  org.junit.Assert method assertEquals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) is all match
```